# Python doesn't recognize zip files as zip files

Tags: python, python-2.x, zip

I iterate through the directories and want to find all zip files and add them to download_all.zip
I am sure there are zip files, but Python doesn't recognize those zip files as zip files. Why is that?

my code:

```
os.chdir(boardpath)
# zf = zipfile.ZipFile('download_all.zip', mode='w')
z = zipfile.ZipFile('download_all.zip', 'w') #creating zip download_all.zip file

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(boardpath):
    for file in files:
        print file
        if file.endswith('.zip'): # find all zip files
                print ('adding', file)
                z.write(file) # error shows: doesn't file is a str object, not a zip file

z.close()
z = zipfile.ZipFile("download_all.zip")
z.printdir()
```

I tried:

```
file.printdir()
# I got the following error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'printdir'
```

Comment: 1) `file` is a string so it's no surprise that it doesn't have the printdir method. 2) what makes you say that "Python doesn't recognize those zip files as zip files"? What are you printing out or debugging that makes you say so?

Comment: oh, I don't know file is a string, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zipfile.Zipfile.write(name), name actually stands for full file path, not just filename.

```
import os #at the top

 if file.endswith('.zip'): # find all zip files  
    filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
    print ('adding', filepath) 
    z.write(filepath) # no error
```

Comment: Code-only answers (especially incomplete ones) are generally confusing to new users who are asking about error messages. Your edit does improve though

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [ZipFile.write's doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write), the `filename` argument must be relative to the archive root. So the following line:

```
z.write(file)
```

Should be:

```
z.write(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(path, file)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `files` that `os/walk()` yields are lists of filenames. These filenames are just **strings** (which don't have a `printdir()` method).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the context management while opening up the zip file archive and writing to it for each file that you find, hence the use of `with`. In addition, since you're walking through a directory structure, you need to full qualify each file's path.

```
import os 
import Zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('download_all.zip', 'w') as zf:
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk('/some_path'):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.zip'):
                zf.write(os.path.join(path, file))
```